# How to change the position of an array element?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a question on how I can change the index of a array element, so that it doesn't come at the 7. position but at position 2 instead...

Is there a function to handle this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Nothing is simpler:

```
array.insert(2, array.delete_at(7))
```

Comment: Ok, now reverse direction. Position 2 to position 7. Maybe not so simple as you think.

Comment: This does not work if you're moving from an index that is before the index you're inserting at! The act of removing will occur before the insertion, so you need to account for the elements shifting before you insert.

Comment: The above comments are wrong, this approach works in all cases. Try it yourself in irb.

Comment: This answer is misleading. While it works, and answers the question, @wizzard is right in that it doesn't work in all scenarios. See my answer below for a way that works in the scenario where the origin index is less than the destination index.

Answer (score 27):

```
irb> a = [2,5,4,6]
=> [2, 5, 4, 6]
irb> a.insert(1,a.delete_at(3))
=> [2, 6, 5, 4]
```

UPD: guys, it works fine with the dest>src:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
a.insert 1, a.delete_at(3)
p a  #=>  [0, 3, 1, 2, 4]

a = [0,1,2,3,4]
a.insert 3, a.delete_at(1)
p a  #=>  [0, 2, 3, 1, 4]
```

What else would you expect? 0,2,1,3,4? I would not call that dest=3

Comment: Thanks for your correct answer. I gave trekd the correct answer, as he still has the newbie bonus.

Comment: I would expect `[0,2,3,1,4]` and I'll explain why in my updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

#### Explanation for beginners

These answers are great. I was looking for a little more explanation on how these answers work. Here's what's happening in the answers above, how to switch elements by value, and links to documentation.

```
# sample array
arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

# suppose we want to move "h" element in position 7 to position 2 (trekd's answer)
arr = arr.insert(2, arr.delete_at(7))
=> ["a", "b", "h", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

This works because `arr.delete_at(index)` deletes the elements at the specified index ('7' in our example above), and returns the value that was in that index. So, running `arr.delete_at(7)` would produce:

```
# returns the deleted element
arr.delete_at(7) 
=> "h"           

# array without "h"
arr
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

Putting it together, the `insert` method will now place this "h" element at position 2. Breaking this into two steps for clarity:

```
# delete the element in position 7
element = arr.delete_at(7)  # "h"
arr.insert(2, element)
=> ["a", "b", "h", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

#### Switching elements by value

Suppose you wanted to move the element in the array whose value is "h", regardless of its position, to position 2. This can easily be accomplished with the index method:

```
arr = arr.insert(2, arr.delete_at( arr.index("h") ))
```

Note: The above assumes that there's only one value of "h" in the array.

#### Documentation

- [Array#delete_at](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/delete_at)
- [Array#insert](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/insert)
- [Array#index](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/index)

Comment: Switching elements by value -> What if you have more "h"

Comment: @AdamLudian you'll just need to be specific as to the behaviour you want. For example, if your array has more than one "h" value, maybe you wouldn't want to run this code at all.

Answer (score 4):

Best way in case you want to swap:

```
array = [4, 5, 6, 7]

array[0], array[3] = array[3], array[0]

array # => [7, 5, 6, 4]
```

Comment: Although neat, this swaps two positions which isn't what the original poster requested.  They wanted to move item 7 to item 2.  So technically this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the position of the other elements in the array you can use the .rotate! (note that the ! at the end of this method changes the actual array) method.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
arr.rotate! -3
arr = [6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This takes the element 8 which is at index 7, and rotates it to an index of 2.

Answer (score 2):

The answers here don't cover both possible scenarios. While the question dealt with an `origin` index higher than the `destination`, if the reverse is true then the solution below won't work:

```
array.insert 7, array.delete_at(2)
```

This is because deleting the value at 2 shifts everything (above 2) down the array by 1. Now our destination index of 7 is pointing at what used to be at index 8.

To fix this, we need to check if the `origin` is less than the `destination` and if so, deduct 1 from the `destination`.

```
origin = 2
destination = 7

destination -= 1 if origin < destination
array.insert destination, array.delete_at(origin)
```

#### For Clarification

It may help to think of this problem in less numerical terms. Consider:

```
employees = [:bob, :jane, :steve, :tama, :susan]
```

I want to move `:jane` in front of `:tama`. I see that `:jane` is at position `1` and `:tama` is at position `3` currently. I think I'll be efficient and do this as a one-liner based upon the positions I know to be true right now:

```
employees.insert 3, employees.delete_at(1)
```

Has this achieved my intended result? No, `:jane` is after `:tama`.

```
[:bob, :steve, :tama, :jane, :susan]
```

Why does this happen? Because the index of the members of the array change above the point of the deleted member, so the index you assumed was referencing the member before the `delete_at` has now changed. To do this properly you'd be better off first removing `:jane`, then looking at the `employees` again to ascertain the index of `:tama` which is now `2` not `3`, then inserting `:jane` at `2` instead.

Comment: I downvoted because this is wrong.   You can view Nakilon's answer to see it demonstrated.

Comment: @fatfrog, please re-read my answer and note that Nakilon's example shows deleting an item from the array at an index that is higher than the index he is inserting it at. That works well as-is but will fail if the reverse is true since the delete operation happens before the insert operation it will affect the index of the item you're targeting to insert before.

Comment: Nakilon updated his answer to include the destination  > origin.  Next time work on verifying your answer.  At least 2 poor chumps may have buggy code now.

Comment: @fatfrog, I've clarified my position. In my opinion, blindly copying Nakilon's one liner  is much more likely to lead to buggy code but it all really depends on ones assumptions about the indexes you're targeting to begin with.

Comment: "Has this achieved my intended result?" Yes it has - :jane is now at index 3

Comment: My intended result: “I want to move :jane in front of :tama.” So no it hasn’t. However I can now see that you’re not interested in seeing this from another perspective so I’ll be leaving the conversation here. Others can make up their own mind.

Comment: You need to address the question asked.  To claim that a solution "doesn't work" (without specifics)  simply because it doesn't meet *you're* intended result when it addresses the question asked is disingenuous on your part.  Thanks for at least updating your answer with specifics so it doesn't leave readers in the lurch.  My work is done here.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't better to use:

```
irb> a = [2,5,4,6]
#=> [2, 5, 4, 6]
irb> a.insert(1, a.pop)
#=> [2, 6, 5, 4]
```

?

Comment: This only works if you want to move the last element, but doesn't work if you want to move another one :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for solution to move **uniq** items up and down the array:

```
module ArrayElementMove
  MustBeUniqArray = Class.new(StandardError)
  ItemNotInArray  = Class.new(StandardError)

  def self.up!(array, item)
    self.check_if_uniq!(array)
    return array if array.first == item
    position = array.index(item) || raise(ItemNotInArray)
    array.insert((position - 1), array.delete_at(position))
  end

  def self.down!(array, item)
    self.check_if_uniq!(array)
    return array if array.last == item
    position = array.index(item) || raise(ItemNotInArray)
    array.insert((position + 1), array.delete_at(position))
  end

  def self.check_if_uniq!(array)
    raise MustBeUniqArray if array.size != array.uniq.size
  end
end
```

spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe ArrayElementMove do
  let(:arr) { [1,2,3,4,5,6] }

  it do
    ArrayElementMove.up!(arr, 4)
    expect(arr).to eq([1,2,4,3,5,6])

    expect(ArrayElementMove.up!(arr, 4).to eq([1,4,2,3,5,6])
    expect(arr).to eq([1,4,2,3,5,6])

    ArrayElementMove.up!(arr, 4)
    expect(arr).to eq([4,1,2,3,5,6])

    ArrayElementMove.up!(arr, 4)
    expect(arr).to eq([4,1,2,3,5,6])
  end

  it do
    ArrayElementMove.down!(arr, 4)
    expect(arr).to eq([1,2,3,5,4,6])

    expect(ArrayElementMove.down!(arr, 4)).to eq([1,2,3,5,6,4])
    expect(arr).to eq([1,2,3,5,6,4])

    expect(ArrayElementMove.down!(arr, 4)).to eq([1,2,3,5,6,4])
    expect(arr).to eq([1,2,3,5,6,4])
  end

  context 'when non uniq array' do
    let(:arr) { [1,4,2,3,4,5,6] }

    it do
      expect { ArrayElementMove.down!(arr, 3) }.to raise_exception(ArrayElementMove::MustBeUniqArray)
      expect(arr).to eq([1,4,2,3,4,5,6])
    end

    it do
      expect { ArrayElementMove.down!(arr, 3) }.to raise_exception(ArrayElementMove::MustBeUniqArray)
      expect(arr).to eq([1,4,2,3,4,5,6])
    end
  end

  context 'when non existing item' do
    it do
      expect { ArrayElementMove.up!(arr, 9) }.to raise_exception(ArrayElementMove::ItemNotInArray)
      expect(arr).to eq([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    end

    it do
      expect { ArrayElementMove.up!(arr, 9) }.to raise_exception(ArrayElementMove::ItemNotInArray)
      expect(arr).to eq([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    end
  end
end
```